# Combining and minifying cross-script variables

Tags: minify

I'm looking to combine and minify my JavaScript files.  I have a question; on my pages I basically have the same library JS files, and then one 'specific' JS file to run code for that page.  I also have variables defined in that specific JS file which are then used elsewhere in the library JS files.  For example, I defined var tablename which is then used in a library file to render out a table using what is set as 'tablename'.

My question is, if I combine all of my JavaScript files from all of my pages into one big JS file, and then include that combined/minified file on my pages, then as a result of combining all of the files then that big JS file will have multiple .ready() events and the same variable tablename will be defined multiple times.  How is this overcome?  Maybe it can't in my situation and I'll need to create a combined/minified file for each of my pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution; YUI Compressor (that I'm using) doesn't munge global variables, and since my tablename variable will be global (not in a function) then it won't get munged.